# Geometric transformation of Schwarz P Triply Periodic Minimal Surface

Tags: geometry, minimal-surfaces

I'm working with the Schwarz P TPMS geometry (which can be seen in this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiZHb.jpg)).

The formulation for such geometry is simply:

$\cos(x) + \cos(y) + \cos(z)$

My intent is to modify the formula in order to "shrink" the surface in the x direction but I'm not managing to do it. What would be the correct modification to accomplish this?

Comment: Your terms don't make a lot of sense to me, but I'm guessing that the answer is $\cos (ax) + \cos y + \cos z$, where $a$ is either less than or greater than $1$, but I don't know which one works for your particular question/formulation.

Comment: I'll try to explain myself better. The P unit cell is made up of three connecting cylinders (one in x-direction, one in y-direction and one in z-direction). I'm using this shape to simulate fluid flow inside it and I would want to reduce the diameter of the x-direction cylinder but I do not know how the mathematical formulation would look like.

Comment: Well, assuming it's defined as an implicit surface, you might want to try $A\cos x  + \cos y + \cos z$ for $A = 2$ or $A = \frac{1}{2}$, or perhaps $\cos x + A \cos y + A \cos z$, and see what it looks like in each of those cases.

Comment: Yes, it is in fact an implicit surface. So I tried your solutions and your four proposals reduce to two surfaces [A](http://imgur.com/a/N5UP9) and [B](http://imgur.com/a/FWdpB) and none of them are what I was looking for because the "cilinders" in z and y directions get elongated and distorted and I'd like to preserve their shape as much as possible.

Comment: Ok so an exponential did the trick $\exp(x^2/18))*\cos(x)+\cos(y)+\cos(z)$ as can be seen [here](https://imgur.com/BAmHn2X). However, the catch is that when I do more than I cell, as [here](https://imgur.com/1tq9GcW) the periodicity is lost. How could I solve this?